# Android: Is it possible to share an image to Instagram, stored in Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: android, google-cloud-storage, instagram, share, firebase-storage

I have an image stored in Google Cloud Storage. I want to allow the user of my app to share it to Instagram. Thus I get the reference to it in Storage, then I get the download URL (an URI object) and put it in the extra data of an intent I use to open Instagram.

But Instagram says that the "image is impossible to load". I think it's because the URI points to the Web URL returned by Cloud Storage instead of a URI pointing to a local file. No? **Is there any way to make my program work using the URI pointing to the Web URL returned by Cloud Storage?**

## Sources

The code is available below:

```
final Intent intent_share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent_share.setType("image/*");

FirebaseStorage firebase_storage = new SetupFirebaseStorage().getFirebaseStorage();
StorageReference storage_reference = firebase_storage.getReference();
storage_reference.child(image_uuid).getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
        intent_share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        activity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent_share, "Share to"));
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "An error occurred during the publication image's URL retrieving.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the [official Instagram's documentation for Android developers](https://www.instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/android-intents/), the Intent has to have the URI pointing to the media path **in the device.**

[image]

However, like you said, you are putting in the Intent the download URL (check the documentation of the method [getDownloadUrl](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference#getDownloadUrl())) instead of the URI pointing to the image in the local device. In fact, the image is not even in your phone yet. What you need to do is to download the image with that URL you got, and then put the URI of the media in the intent.

Comment: Maybe they wrote "on a device" without thinking about the possibility of the image being stored elsewhere, for example... in a remote device (in my context, Google's Cloud Storage servers)? Is there really no way to run my program this way, that is, without having to temporarily store the iamge on my user's phone? It would be one more step, unnecessary and I would have to deal with the "temporary" aspect of it, and it's boring.

Comment: Even though I am not absolutely certain about this, I am pretty sure that by device they mean the phone. Also, how could the Instagram app get access to your own Google Cloud Storage if they don't have the proper credentials, all you give to the app in the Intent is a path to a file. @JarsOfJam-Scheduler

Comment: What is more, you can do the following experiment: do you use Google Photos in your device to store your pictures in the cloud? You can click the "Share" button in one of your pictures in the cloud and choose to share it in Instagram. As soon as you do that, the sharing is not immediate. Before Instagram opens, you can see a Loader that says "Downloading image".